# '0000-00-00 00:00:00' as an invalid timestamp

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp, google-bigquery

When I try to load a data file to BigQuery, it gives me an error with MySQL's default timestamp value (at least from mysqldump) of `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. Is there a way to change my json file to allow these values in `datetime` fields (see below)?

> Errors:
>
> gs://pfam31/pfamseq_part_04: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 11664; errors: 1. (error code: invalid)
>
> gs://pfam31/pfamseq_part_04: Could not parse '0000-00-00 00:00:00' as datetime for field created (position 13) starting at location 8743229 (error code: invalid)

```
[
  {
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "pfamseq_acc",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "pfamseq_id",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "seq_version",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "crc64",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "md5",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "description",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "evidence",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "length",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "species",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "taxonomy",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "is_fragment",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "sequence",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "updated",
    "type": "TIMESTAMP"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "created",
    "type": "DATETIME"
  },
  {
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "ncbi_taxid",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "auto_architecture",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "treefam_acc",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "swissprot",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not set years/months/date to zeros.TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC. 
for more check [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)

Comment: From those docs "MySQL does not accept TIMESTAMP values that include a zero in the day or month column or values that are not a valid date. The sole exception to this rule is the special “zero” value '0000-00-00 00:00:00'."

Comment: That may me a valid date in MySQL, but it is not in BigQuery. You may also try doing a string replace on the CSV file to replace these zero values with NULL before loading into BigQuery.

Comment: alternative: import as String to BigQuery, then run transformations inside BQ to save ETL time

Answer (score 0):

TIMESTAMP type in GBQ has a range of 0001-01-01 00:00:00 to 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999 UTC (from Google's documentation)